# Como realizar um loop no openMp para contar linhas de um arquivo texto?

Tags: c++, openmp

Como realizar um loop usando a biblioteca `OpenMP` para contar as linhas um arquivo?

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (string line; getline(file, line); ) {
    count++;
}
```

Deste modo ele não executa, parece que ele só aceita `for` de modo normal, onde se deve realizar o `loop` de um numero tal a tal.

Comment: Você realmente precisa da biblioteca? Dá para fazer isso com C++ puro. Veja minha resposta.

Comment: @LucasHenrique, preciso sim.

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que não é possível determinar o número de iterações no inicio do loop. Saber onde começa cada linha requer já ter lido a linha anterior e saber o número total de linhas requer que todas já tenham sido lidas. Dentro do loop você escreveu `count++;`. Ou seja, para saber o valor de `count` e incrementar ele precisa que a iteração anterior já tenha se completado. Por fim, não há nada paralelizável nesse código.

Algumas soluções para isso podem ser:

1. Leia todas as linhas do arquivo em um array previamente e itere sobre o array de forma paralelizada de forma similar a como você pretendia fazer.
2. Mapeie o arquivo em páginas da memória (o sistema operacional tem funções para isso), identifique o inicio e o tamanho de cada linha e guarde esse par de inteiros em um array. Por fim itere sobre o array de forma paralelizada.
3. Crie uma thread produtora que vai ler o arquivo linha por linha e uma ou mais threads consumidoras, que vão processar as linhas lidas. Aqui não acho que o OpenMP vá ajudar, mas a biblioteca padrão tem classes primitivas que podem ajudar.

Estou assumindo, é claro, que o processamento de cada linha é **muito** mais custoso que o ato de ler a linha do arquivo. Isso é, no entanto, improvável. Operações de leitura/escrita no disco são o gargalo na maioria dos casos, e você não pode paralelizar o disco.

Comment: consegui através deste código. `int countLines(ifstream &file) {
 
 int count = 0;

 #pragma omp parallel reduction(+:count)
 for (string line; getline(file, line); ) {
        count++;
 }

 return count;
}`

Comment: @Macario1983 mas como afirmei, o código não será realmente executado paralelamente.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso com C++ "puro":

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream exemplo;
    exemplo.open("exemplo.txt");
    std::string linha;
    for(int i = 0; std::getline(exemplo /*envia*/,linha/*recebe*/); i++);
}
```

Comment: O exemplo dele já é "C++ puro". Ele quer paralelizar com o OMP.

Answer (score 0):

Ola, tenta a seguinte solucao passa todo conteudo do ficheiro para um array, logo paralelizas as operacoes no array, ou entao tenta paralelizar com a utilizando mpi-IO, espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Seria excelente se puder juntar exemplos para os passos que sugeriu. (E bemvindo ao Stackoverflow!)